# Корректно ли употреблять предлог СПУСТЯ в отношении будущего времени?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги

> Хочу, чтоб годам вопреки, так же были мы близки,
>   Так же были мы близки двадцать лет спустя.

(Песня Юрия Антонова)

Корректно ли употреблять предлог СПУСТЯ в отношении будущего времени ("двадцать лет спустя" в смысле "когда пройдет двадцать лет")?

Answer (score 2):

**Хочу, чтоб годам вопреки так же были мы близки, Так же были мы близки двадцать лет спустя.**

**СПУСТЯ**, предлог. кого-что. По прошествии какого-л. времени.

Вообще говоря, предлог СПУСТЯ употребляется в отношении будущего времени, например:

Возможно, **спустя** некоторое время (= через некоторое время) **рынок  покажет**, какие направления деятельности совершенно бесперспективны, а какие, наоборот, нужно активно развивать. [Павел Куприянов. Адвокат клиента // «Computerworld», 2004]

Что касается песни, то там есть **стилистическая погрешность**, но она связана с формой глагола.

**Ирреальное значение будущего** заключено в союзе ЧТОБЫ (его передает частица БЫ в составе этого союза).  Но **повтор затемняет эту связь,** и мы получаем: "так же были мы близки двадцать лет спустя" уже без частицы БЫ.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "двадцать лет спустя" привязывает более поздний момент времени к более раннему (обычно отмеченному каким-то событием), но *отличному от настоящего* времени: в этом случае такое выражение излишне и требуется более простое "через двадцать лет". Думаю, что не должно быть ограничений для расположения во времени более позднего момента:

> В позапрошлом году он оформил страховку и рассчитывает двадцать лет
>   спустя разбогатеть.
>
> Через год он хочет поступить в университет, пять лет спустя он его
>   закончит.

В повествовании будущее время с таким оборотом может использоваться при ретроспективном описании событий:

> *...  что государь пойдет навстречу его роду, зная, что на службу юноша*
>   *все равно **выйдет несколько лет спустя**.*
>
> Дмитрий Володихин, Пожарский (сер. Великие исторические персоны)

В этом смысле "поэтическую вольность" в тексте песни (вероятно, допустимую в рамках жанра) можно усмотреть лишь в том, что отсчёт ведётся от текущего момента.